# PHP Variable in Select Statement

Tags: php, mysql, html, variables, select

I've written this PHP-Script which is working, and now I want to change the row name into a variable to (not sure if row is correct), I mean the "name" from the *select **name***...
I've tried nearly everything, but nothing gave me the right result.
I know that the normal thing how I can use variables in a statement like ("'. $var .'") won't work.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$id = $_GET["id"]; //ID OF THE CURRENT CONTACT
$user = $_GET["user"];  //ID OF THE CURRENT USERS

$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE contact_id='". mysql_real_escape_string( $id ) ."' and user_id='1';");

$retval = mysql_fetch_object($query)->name;

$retval = trim($retval);
echo $retval;
?>
```

Comment: I noticed your other questions are in English, you might get more answers if this one was as well.

Comment: use alt+shift and come back :-)

Comment: I can't understand even the translated version: http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476108/php-variable-in-select-statement&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&twu=1&usg=ALkJrhg-4cxdFU1raaAewkI6wMl0PgQ_Cw

Comment: Please put your question in English to help the maximun number or persons to read it and help you.

Comment: i've translated it into my poor english ;)

Comment: a variable in select statement. it's quite unusual task. I believe no one here ever used that. Most likely there is a common way to achieve the same goal

Comment: i thougt it would be better if i use it in the statement the whole thing looks more clean i think. but it make no difference or i am wrong?

Comment: It is very dangerous, your way. At least that variable should be properly escaped. And it gonna be pain if there will be more than one field name. So, it cannot be any better as it would be much more code if make it properly.

Comment: but isn't it secure enough when i look if the $field variable is anything like "name", ... ? with esp. the strpos function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is much easier isn't it?

```
$sql_insert = 
"INSERT INTO customers (        
`name`,
`address`,
`email`,
`phone`
) 
VALUES (        
'$name',
'$address',     
'$email',
'$phone'
)";
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. it's thousand times easier to read than all other solutions. is this somehting new in a current version of php or was this always possible already?

Answer (score 3):

Is it this you're looking for? Even your question in German isn't that clear to me :

```
$field = 'name';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM contacts WHERE contact_id='". mysql_real_escape_string( $id ) ."' and user_id='1';");
$retval = mysql_fetch_object($query)->$field;
```

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Depends on where $field comes from and if it's properly escaped.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Not as is, if he just gets the $name from a GET/POST var without checking, then yes you have a point.

Comment: @dbemerlin oh can you tell me how to properly escape?

Comment: Why on earth is there a "$retval = $retval = " on the last line? (Also, why not just use mysql_real_escape_string around $field?)

Comment: @middaparka because mysql_real_escape_string would help nothing

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - Why not? As long as the $field and $id variables are escaped there's a basic level of protection in place.

Comment: @middaparka: That was a stupid copy/paste error on my part. Corrected.

Comment: @middaparka because you do not understand what does this function do. `$field = "Billy Joe";`. Go escape it.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Don't be a smartass, have a look at your code below, and compare it to what I posted without assuming things that the OP didn't even ask for. Can you tell me what "script.php?id=Billy%20Joe" would actually do on your code snippet? btw `SELECT *` is evil, you should NEVER, EVER use it.

Comment: But I am. I am ass but I am smart and proud of it. It will merely return no rows. what's wrong with it? And you looks  ridiculous with that "NEVER, EVER use it!!!111" mindless prayer when talking of selecting just a single row. Everyone who repeat it, have ten thousand times worst holes in their code. Every friggin one.

Comment: I beg my pardon for the tone. But i jut hate to see improper solutions. escaping works only within quoted strings. That's the way it works. It wouldn't help with field name where you can't use quotes. So, one who doing it that way, lays a trap for themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to accept the other answer now because it's much cleaner and i think it prevents many errors with ' or "

Answer (score 3):

You can usi it something like this. Currently i assume you get only one row back and want to use only one field.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$id = $_GET["id"]; //ID DES DERZEITIGEN KONTAKTES
$user = $_GET["user"];  //ID DES DERZEITIGEN USERS

//Use variable inside closures `` and just in case escape it, depends how you get variable
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `".mysql_real_escape_string($variable)."` FROM contacts WHERE contact_id='". mysql_real_escape_string( $id ) ."' and user_id='1';");


if (!$query) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query); //Retriev first row, with multiple rows use mysql_fetch_assoc
$retval = $row['0']; //Retriev first field

$retval = trim($retval); 
echo $retval;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Please post in English. Everyone else does.
- Try using a different fetch method - fetch an associative array, then use the dynamic parameter to retrieve whatever column it is you need.
- Have you considered using PDO?

Comment: I also suggest using PDO. It is much more better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confusing matters (unintentionally) due to your use of the word 'row'. Judging by your example you mean field/column. It sounds like you wish to specify the fields to select using a variable which can be done by any of these methods...

```
$fields = "name, age";

$sql = "SELECT $fields FROM table";
$sql = "SELECT {$fields} FROM table";
$sql = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM table";
```

**NB** it is important that you have secure date in the $fields element, I would suggest using a whitelist of allowed values i.e.

```
// assuming $_POST['fields'] looks something like array('name','age','hack');
$allowed = array('name', 'age');
$fields = array();

foreach ($_POST['fields'] as $field) {
   if (in_array($field, $allowed)) {
      $fields[] = $field;
   }
$fields = implode(', ', $fields);
```

Comment: i've tried this: ".$fields." but it doesn't work for me, so i use this one $fields

Comment: mikep, all three solutions I gave work perfectly fine, if you had problems implementing it, then that's because your implementation was messed up, most like by messing up single/double quoted strings. It is perfectly valid PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo trim($result['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never put a variable into field list.
If want a variable field name, select *
and then use your variable to fetch particular field

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]); //ID DES DERZEITIGEN KONTAKTES
$user = $_GET["user"];  //ID DES DERZEITIGEN USERS

$query  = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_id='$id' and user_id='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

//and finally
$fieldname = "name";
$retval = $row[$fieldname];

echo $retval;
?>
```

Comment: yes i could do it this way to, you'r right, but the query should be  "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_id='$id' and user_id='1'" instead  "SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE contact_id='$id' and user_id='1'".